# Returned XML but how do I display it in container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I have some XML code I returned. The question is, how do I push it to `$("#container").html`?

Would I do something like find the ID and push the details (ows_kxoi) to the container?

```js
$(xData.responseXML).find("z:row, ows_ID=1").push($("#container").html)
```

The returned XML:

```
<z:row ows_Title='Safeway - 24-7 Nurseline' ows_ID='1'
  ows_kxoi='&lt;div class=&quot;ExternalClassE873CA13CAC245429C873C746B5A144E&quot;&gt;24-7 Nurseline&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;ExternalClassE873CA13CAC245429C873C746B5A144E&quot;&gt;&lt;div&gt;866-670-5681&amp;#160;Option 6​&lt;/div&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;/div&gt;' ows_MetaInfo='1;#'
  ows__ModerationStatus='0' ows__Level='1'
  ows_UniqueId='1;#{7F7F703A-8EAB-4C54-9DB4-7BE5AF1924C1}'
  ows_owshiddenversion='6' ows_FSObjType='1;#0'/>
```

Comment: Are you just trying to display the xml in a _div_? or _textarea_?

Comment: where does the XML come from? Is it saved in xData?

Comment: xml is coming from a sharepoint list. Its being pulled in and I write it to the   console.log(xData.responseText);   All the data comes back, but I want to retrieve the specific data from ows_ID=1 and display the ows_kxoi

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: dataSet.SiteUrl + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "html",
        data: soapEnv,
        success: function(result){
            processResult();
            var data = $.parseHTML(result);
            $('#container').html($(data).attr('ows_kxoi'));
        },
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
}
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/d35dtn6e/)
This will set the content in the element with id 'container'.

Comment: i get an undefined error. Do i have to define xData?

Comment: Is there a specific info from the XML that you want to display in the `container`?

Comment: yes, i wanna display the ows_kxoi data. But I guess I need to include that too

Comment: I updated the answer and added a JSFiddle. Have a look at it and let me know if it works for you

Comment: almost but the data is from responseXML not data. I need to somehow change var x = $.parseHTML(data);     I tried  var x = $.parseHTML($(xData.responseXML));   but no luck

Comment: no matter what I put in there, says undefined. I tried var x = $.parseHTML($(xData.responseXML));

Comment: You can replace `data` by your `responseXML`. Can you provide your ajax code?

Comment: my ajax  function getData(){
            $.ajax({
                url: dataSet.SiteUrl + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "xml",
                data: soapEnv,
                complete: processResult,
                contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
            });            
        }

Comment: I updated the code in the answer, have a look at it. Use the `success` event and then process and set the data in the container at that time as the data will be available in the function within the variable `result`

Comment: Like i mentioned earlier, I need to tie in the ID as well, for instance it will be multiple ones- so I cant have the   $('#container').html($(data).attr('ows_kxoi'));  hardcoded in the processresult. I need something that uses the  ID=1 then show the $('#container').html($(data).attr('ows_kxoi'));  for that ID

Comment: Do you have an example of multiple IDs xml and what data you expect to be displayed?

Comment: for example seems like i need something like  $(xData.responseXML).find("z:row,ows_ID=1").append('#container').html($(data).attr('ows_kxoi'));  a way for me to find that row and Id and append that data to the container.    if i click another button and want to pull id=2 but the ows_kxoi data will pertain to that specific row

Comment: l<z:row ows_Title='Safeway - 24-7 line' ows_ID='1' ows_kxoi='&lt;div class=&quot;ExternalClassE873CA13CAC245429C873C746B5A144E&quot;&gt;24-7 line&lt;/div&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;ExternalClassE873CA13CAC245429C873C746B5A144E&quot;&gt;&lt;div&gt;866-670-5681&amp;#160;Option 6​&lt;/' />
   <z:row ows_Title='Safe - A- ASD' ows_ID='5' ows_kxoi='&lt;div class=&quot;ExternalClassB18CE69EF2AD4746B2889E18D9A822A0&quot;&gt;Autism Spectrum Disorder- ASD  Monday- Friday 8&amp;#58;00 AM - 6&amp;#58;00 PM&l' />